# Primavera EPPM P6 Rest Service vs. P6 Web Services

Tags: primavera

We are working on building a small tool to tie into a portion of Primavera. The official documentation points users toward installing [EPPM Web Services](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E58731_01/English/Integration_Documentation/Web_Services/Programmers_Guide/helpmain.htm?toc.htm?34316.htm), and using the supported SOAP endpoints.

The interesting thing is there is a REST service backing EPPM P6. For example:

/p6/rest/activities/loadAssignmentsData?activityId=35874&activityType=TT_Task&columns=ResourceName%2CRoleName%2CPlannedUnits%2CActualUnits%2CPlannedUnitsPerTime%2CAtCompletionCost%2CLocation

/p6/rest/activities/loadGeneralData?activityId=35879

/p6/rest/admin/location/load*

All the functionality I need appears to already be exposed through a REST API.  The issue is that it does not appear to be supported officially.

Does anyone have any more insight on this?  Does Primavera have a supported REST interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though P6 EPPM appears to use it's own REST service, this doesn't seem to be supported so we've fallen back to proxying all of our calls through our own REST service to the Web Services SOAP endpoints.  Frankly, it sucks :)